# ERROR in main.min.js from UglifyJs

Tags: javascript, webpack

У меня произошла странная ошибка.
История такова: мы с другом работаем над одним проектом собираем вебпаком. Вечером я пушу в репозиторий, все хорошо, вебпак все собирает, никаких ошибок.

Сутра друг мне отписал, что он скачал реп, и у него выбивает ошибку

```
ERROR in main.min.js from UglifyJs
```

У меня все было хорошо, поэтому я решил удалить репозиторий локально и стянуть его с гита. В итоге у меня выбило ту же ошибку, повторюсь до этого ее не было. **Код никак не менялся, вообще ничего не менялось.**